# Org-mode beamer - How to create a short title, author, date?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

Is there any easy way in adding a short title, author, date, etc. in the .org file, without messing around with the generated .tex file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My (in progress) Org Beamer refcard could help you.

See on https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer, in particular the section "Creating a title page".

UPDATE -- Something like the following would do it?

```
#+BIND: org-latex-title-command "\\title{De leerplandoelstellingen}\n\\date[mei 2014]{9 mei 2014}\n\\maketitle"
```

(that's a way to fiddle with the title, but directly from the Org file...)

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't help! I'm looking for **short** title, author date and not the normal (=long) version

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer since it is at least a solution without messing around the .tex file. However, I hoped for something cleaner, like #+SHORT_TITLE, but maybe this can be defined somehow?

Comment: You could try and ask on the Org ML. However, as it'd be Beamer (or LaTeX) specific, I don't think such a thing will ever be added. But you can try.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can define `#+SHORT_TITLE` but it involves editing 2 elisp files. You need to find your `ox.el` and `ox-beamer.el` files, mine are located in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20150330` directory. There are also some compiled files `ox.elc` and `ox-beamer.elc`. I recommend you create a backup of all these files before continuing.

In file `ox.el` go to line 118 and add the `short_title` line as shown below:

```
 114│    (:section-numbers nil "num" org-export-with-section-numbers)
 115│    (:select-tags "SELECT_TAGS" nil org-export-select-tags split)
 116│    (:time-stamp-file nil "timestamp" org-export-time-stamp-file)
 117│    (:title "TITLE" nil nil space)
 118│    (:short_title "SHORT_TITLE" nil nil space) ;; Additional line        
 119│    (:with-archived-trees nil "arch" org-export-with-archived-trees)
 120│    (:with-author nil "author" org-export-with-author)
 121│    (:with-clocks nil "c" org-export-with-clocks)
 122│    (:with-creator nil "creator" org-export-with-creator)
```

Save the file. Remove th `ox.elc` file (ensure you have a backup) and byte compile the file. This can be done from within emacs using `M-x byte-compile-file` and entering the file name, ensure it completes without error.

Then open file `ox-beamer.el` and make the following changes.

```
 860│     ;; 7. Title
 861│     (let ((short_title (plist-get info :short_title)))
 862│       (format "\\title[%s]{%s}\n" short_title title))
```

Save, remove the old ox-beamer.elc and byte compile. Restart emacs and you can now use `#+SHORT_TITLE:` as you wish.

Your line numbers may be different but I've included the surrounding code so you should be able to find/replace easily.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to achieve the same effect:

```
#+TITLE: Short title
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \subtitle{long title}
```

This requires that you make the two titles play well together, so it does not look silly.

Credit: Learnt about the `BEAMER_HEADER` thing from https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question. I got here while searching for a solution to the same problem. And I thought others in the same boat may benefit from a cleaner solution.

Including the following before/after `#+TITLE:` should do the job:

```
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \title[short title]{long title}
```

Note that it replaces whatever you set in the `#TITLE:` line. Of course, I'm not sure if this was a possibility at the time OP asked the question.